# How to insert value of TextField into List Item in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to make a app. On button click on the bottom right of the screen there appears a dialog window(popup). On "Done" click the popup window closes (close_dialog method), and a new List Item appears. The text of the List Item is expected to be obtained from MDTextField of the popup by this code:

```
    mylist = TwoLineAvatarListItem(text = DialogContent().textfield.text,
        secondary_text = "1,2,3...")
```

As far as I know I need to refer to `DialogContent` class from another class `Container` in the .kv file, but I don't know how to do it properly. How can I fix it?

Code.py:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineAvatarListItem

Window.size = (288, 511)

class DialogContent(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Container(Screen):
    dialog = None

    def show_dialog(self, *args):
        '''
        Create group creation popup
        '''
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Create new group",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=DialogContent(),
                auto_dismiss=False
            )
        self.dialog.open()

    def close_dialog(self, *args):
        '''
        Close popup on Done click
        '''
        self.dialog.dismiss()
        self.new_window()

    def new_window(self, *args):
        '''
        Create new group button
        '''
        mylist = TwoLineAvatarListItem(text = DialogContent().textfield.text,
            secondary_text = "1,2,3...")
        self.mdlist.add_widget(mylist)


class grudget4App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        container = Container()
        scroll = ScrollView()
        return container

if __name__ == '__main__':
    grudget4App().run()
```

Code .kv:

```
<DialogContent>:
    textfield: textfield
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "120dp"

    MDTextField:
        id: textfield
        hint_text: "Group name"

    MDFlatButton:
        id: btn1
        text: "Done"
        text_color: self.theme_cls.primary_color
        on_release: app.root.close_dialog()

<Container>:
    mdlist: mdlist
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.89
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: mdlist
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.95, 'y': 0.05}
        icon: "icon.png"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        on_release:
            root.show_dialog()

    Screen:
        NavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                Screen:
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        MDToolbar:
                            title: ''
                            size_hint: 1, 0.14
                            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                            elevation:10
                        Widget:
            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
    mylist = TwoLineAvatarListItem(text = DialogContent().textfield.text,
        secondary_text = "1,2,3...")
```

is creating a new instance of `DialogContent`, unrelated to the `DialogContent` that appears in the display. To access the correct instance use:

```
    mylist = TwoLineAvatarListItem(text = self.dialog.content_cls.textfield.text,
        secondary_text = "1,2,3...")
```